# How to clone entire VeraCrypt encrypted system drive and mount it later on Windows 10 to copy selected files?

Tags: clone, dd, clonezilla, veracrypt

I'm doing a fresh install of Windows and I need to make a copy of all files in my system drive so I can restore them later.

I want to clone entire drive with dd tool (I'm going to use clonezilla).
Then I'm going to install fresh copy of Windows 10 and restore selected files from cloned image.

My questions are

1. Should I make dd clone of entire drive or all partitions separately? Clonezilla allows you to choose either and I don't know which is suitable for *entire system drive encryption*
2. How do I later mount that dd clone image on another system (Windows)?

Comment: There are lots of things that can go wrong. if you already have another volume that will hold the data, consider instead copying the unencrypted contents (and perhaps cherry-picking the specific files you want). its likely to save you time. whatever you do, be sure to test the contents of the copy BEFORE you overwrite the source disk.

Comment: The point is I don't have will or time to cherry pick files because: 1) copying tons of small files takes long time 2) I don't want to store them unencrypted on external storage because I will need to wipe it afterwards 3) I want to pick files I need after I have fresh system installed because I will know better what else I'm missing yet. Yes, I'm perfectly aware I need to test copy before I overwrite source. Thanks for input

Comment: If you use Windows tools to image the whole drive, e.g. Macrium Reflect, you can mount the image under Windows as another drive. Imaging can be done from a USB rescue disk or from a *mounted* Windows partition using Volume Shadow Copy. Mount the image as writable in order to access files with VeraCrypt (this does not actually write to the image on disk, only to the copy in memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of steps I ended up doing:

1. Boot Kali Linux or any other live Linux distribution with `guymager` tool installed. Use `guymager` tool to acquire raw image of your system disk. It's much safer and usually faster than using `dd` by hand.
2. You need to convert raw image to VHDX image to mount it on Windows. You're going to need `vhdtool.exe` and `vhdxtool.exe`.
3. Firstly, convert raw image to VHD format.

   ```
   .\vhdtool.exe /convert G:\image-2017-12-29.dd
   ```

   Also, change its extension, because `vhdtool.exe` is not going to do it for you.

   ```
   Rename-Item G:\image-2017-12-29.dd G:\image-2017-12-29.vhd
   ```
4. Convert VHD image to VHDX format.

   ```
   .\vhdxtool.exe upgrade -f G:\image-2017-12-29.vhd
   ```
5. You now have VHDX image file that you can mount on your system and then open it with VeraCrypt.

I have even managed to boot my cloned VHD (not VHDX though) disk in VirtualBox inside the original system.

#### Tools you need:

[`vhdtool.exe`](http://www.techieshelp.com/downloads/VhdTool.exe)

```
SHA-1: 0ff2994929e5a193369b3ccfdbb86551a9a416d8
```

[`vhdxtool.exe`](http://www.systola.com/support/KB200001/)

```
SHA-1: 9cc4c58a9b14057d2b30107c61b6ce006b36b4eb
```